# OSX List Component Objective-C

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I am a beginner at Objective-C I have been looking all over Google and Xcode to find an OSX list component. I have not found any yet, and I would like to find a list like the one in the red box below:[image: Disk Utility]
I just want to find a list component. Whenever I Google search, all that comes up is stuff about how to make a list programmatically in Objective-C, making mutable lists in Objective-C, etc... Would love to find a list component. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the specific view you have highlighted with [F-Script Anywhere](http://www.fscript.org) indicates that it's an [NSOutlineView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/). That said, I haven't seen it do anything that actually requires the outline parts of NSOutlineView (collapsing multiple rows into a single one), so I'm guessing that for your purposes, its superclass [NSTableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/) will suffice.

Comment: So how would I use the NSOutlineView? I tried an NSTableView, but the column header was still there and I could not delete it.

Comment: Table headers can be removed by setting the NSTableView's `headerView` property to `nil`, or by unchecking the "Headers" checkbox in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thank you so much! FYI: I couldn't find the Headers checkbox in the interface builder but just set the property to nil - works.